# ignoring auth.getuid might be null

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

I created an app that uses `Firebase authentication`.

I use it in my app `auth.getUid()` pretty much and I keep getting the warning that it might be null.

My question is if the users need to sign in into the app in order to use it, doesn't it guarantee that the `auth.getUid()` won't be null? Can I just ignore it in that case?

What can suddenly cause the user not to be signed in?

The firebase dependencies that im using in my app:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:19.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.1'
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you add the firebase dependencies versions you are using, with question

Comment: Added the dependencies mate

Comment: I think that's a fair warning  . Since it can null when your user is signed out from the Firebase . Logout reason can be manual or session out . So you should be checking `if(auth.getCurrentUser()!=null)` each time u perform any operation on firebase.

Comment: ok so let say that I use auth.getUId in my class, you recommend that the first time I use it to write something like: if(auth.getCurrentUser() == null){return to sign in screen}? there wont be manual logout unless they click on it but I didnt know there is session out

Comment: yes if you using only firebase as server which manage login session. If not then just call firebase authentication again no need to go to Sign in screen..

Comment: What do you mean by writing call firebase login?